# how to deal with multiple titles and multiple documents?

Tags: document-classes, document-configuration

I am compiling my dissertation which is composed with several separate papers (with independent LaTeX code).

I have a title for my dissertation and want to insert my individual papers with their own titles (different authors, etc., for each paper).

Someone suggested use

```
\begin{document}
\include{paper1}
\include{paper2}
\end{document}
```

where `paper1` has the codes as

```
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't solve my problem.

For each individual latex code for the individual paper, I have title code outside of the `\begin{document}`.

Any suggestion about how to insert the entire LaTeX code of a academic paper, A, into another academic paper, B, while remain everything not changed for A.

Comment: Have a look at [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone).

Comment: You can try either doc­mute (http://ctan.org/pkg/docmute) or combine (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/combine)

Answer (score 4):

Try this!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\title{First Article}
\author{First Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\end{document}
```

Save as paper1.tex

Then, create a master file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Introduction}
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{paper1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=1-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{paper2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Save as myDissertation.tex

Comment: Where have you been all my life. Thank you for this

Answer (score 3):

There are broadly two ways to proceed here, and which is easier/'better' depends on your exact requirements.

The first is simply to typeset each sub-document separately and then create the main document using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). You can then use `\includepdf` to add each file, with the main title *etc.* in the main file

```
\documentclass{reprot} % or similar
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\title{...}
\author{...}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\includepdf ....
```

You may want a table of contents, which is doable this way with a little effort. Page numbers can also be added to the included PDFs: you'll probably want to supress them in the sub-documents if you do this.

The second approach is to use for example the [`combine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine) package to allow multiple documents to be typeset in one run. There are some restrictions on what will and won't work with `combine`, so that may depend on the document class(es) and packages in use in the sub-documents.

As I say, the exact detail here depends on your situation. I'd recommend focussing things a bit by thinking about the above and asking a new question once you've got a reasonable idea of what makes sense for you.