# How to use more than one document class

Tags: document-classes

I want to set a journal (using the `book` document class) that contains more than one article (using the `article` document class).

The document classes available are only for separate articles, not for a journal of articles. I tried to use the `\input` and `\include` commands to load more than one article, but it didn't work.

I have studied [how to deal with multiple titles and multiple documents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106620/how-to-deal-with-multiple-titles-and-multiple-documents). The second option from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127799/18674) has the disadvantage that to use the [`combine`](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine) package,

> "All the individual documents should be of the same class (e.g., all article or all report)." ([combine doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf))

This is not what I want. But, if using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), each article starts from page 1. What is the solution?

Comment: See this [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106620/how-to-deal-with-multiple-titles-and-multiple-documents) and its answers and comments. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Document classes do not define what sort of document a document is, it simply provides high-level formatting definitions. You should can only use one document class per document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I have studied [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106620/how-to-deal-with-multiple-titles-and-multiple-documents). Two option has disadvantage. To use [combine](http://ctan.org/pkg/combine), "All the individual documents should be of the same class (e.g., all article or all report)." [combine doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/combine/combine.pdf). This is not what I want. But, if using a [pdfpages](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages), each article starts from page 1. What is the solution?

Comment: @EdyJo: are you the same person posting the original question? You may want to ask to the mod to merge your accounts to avoid confusion.

Comment: Proper macro placement (`\title` and friends after `\begin{document}` and the the `docmute` package is your friend. I do not really remember what `combine` actually does, its been years sinces I've used it last